# Crash Reports on Production Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, assert

I have my application installed on my iPhone by deploying from Xcode with my iPhone connected. When I contain a **crash report** from **Window** > **Devices** > my iPhone > **View Device Logs** and selected my crash report. I see only this:

[image: device crash log]

but i want to see this

[image: xcode console]

I used `NSAssert( 0, @"message");` to cause this. I just created a `LoggingAssertionHandler : NSAssertionHandler` to handle the asserts but this prevents the app to create a crash report on the device logs :P

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for? If you're running from Xcode, your app is in debug mode and assertions will cause it to crash. If you're in release mode, assertions shouldn't be an issue.. It sounds like don't really need to do anything, except remove your NSAssertionHandler.. Check this out:
http://nshipster.com/nsassertionhandler/

Comment: Yeah, I'm in release mode and my app crashed and I wanted to see what the assertion on the report under the device logs